# Need help configuring JavaScript- and JSON-powered localization for a web app

Tags: javascript, json, localization, offline

I'm trying to configure a web application that can use client-side JavaScript for localization (as it has to be able to run offline). I've set up a function and a JSON array in my JavaScript like so:

```
var l10n = {
    "getMessage": function(msg) {
        return locales.en.msg;
    }
}
```

and

```
var locales = {
    "en": {
        "applicationName": "This is the application name!",
        "msg": "Looks like we've gotta problem."
    }
}
```

But if, for example, I enter the command `l10n.getMessage("applicationName")` the script always returns the "msg" string ("Looks like we've gotta problem." which I've put there for debugging).

The problem is obviously with my `l10n.getMessage()` function. For all I know, it could be a really simple solution, but with my basic JavaScript knowledge, I can't work out how to fix it. How would I best go about fixing this so that it returns the message for the desired string?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's actually a simple syntax fix. Use bracket notation to retrieve a property off an object using a variable:

```
var l10n = {
    "getMessage": function(msg) {
        return locales.en[msg];
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wC4PN/

Comment: should we use double quotes for **getMessage**

Comment: @gowri They’re not necessary.